# My Van Burns Oil Quickly With No Smoke or Visible Leak

Tags: oil-leak

I have a 1997 Dodge 3500 Van that uses 1 quart of oil every 400 miles.There are no visible leaks, no blue or grey smoke.

Comment: Have you checked the coolant?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's not being burnt. If you're [somewhat] lucky, you will lift the van up and find that there is oil on the bottom of the engine leaking from some seal (oil pan, valve cover seals, crankshaft seal, rear main seal, camshaft seals, are common culprits). If you're not lucky, you'll open the coolant bottle and find chocolate milk-looking coolant. Also check the oil dipstick for chocolate milk. This indicates a head gasket failure.